# SharePoint 2010 REST services

Tags: 2010, rest

I'm having a bit of trouble using the SharePoint 2010 REST services on one of our servers. We have two production servers, and if I point my system to one of the servers I am able to connect to the REST service API with no trouble. However, if I point it to the other server I get a 401 unauthorised error.

It's the same SharePoint service on both servers, our environment uses a load balancer to divide traffic between them, and both share the same database.

Can anyone think why this might be happening? I could understand if it just wasn't working at all, but I'm puzzled as to why it works perfectly on one box but not the other.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Using browser are you able to open up the site by direct url to the second server?

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes. I can browse to my SharePoint site by direct URL on both servers with no trouble. However, when I use the REST URL on one box I get the result I expect, but on the other I get an error message stating that it could not load type: system.data.services.providers.idataserviceupdateprovider

Comment: Actually, that may have answered my question. On googling that error, it looks like there may be an update from Microsoft that needs installed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both servers has latest ADO.Net Data Services installed

Reference

http://blog.hompus.nl/2010/03/26/could-not-load-type-idataserviceupdateprovider-when-using-rest-with-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a HotFix for .net 3/5 SP1 on one server, which is also part of [pre requisite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(v=office.14).aspx) of SharePoint 2010(`ADO.NET Data Services Update for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1`).

Now install the required hotfix as per your Windows Server OS.

[for Windows Server 2008 SP2](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=163519)

[for Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=163524)